# SQL Server Foreign Key Auditing/Tracking

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a SQL Server 2008 DB with foreign keys that are mysteriously vanishing.  The DB is accessed by numerous pieces of custom-built software, MS Excel queries, and through SQL Server Management Studio.  I would like to set up some kind of logging/auditing when a foreign key is added, modified, or deleted from the database.  How would I go about doing that?  Ideally, the changes would be written to a SQL table and help identify who made the change.

Comment: http://www.sqlbook.com/sql-server/using-ddl-triggers-in-sql-server-to-audit-database-objects/

Comment: I can't seem to mark this as the answer (new to posting on Stack Overflow), but the example in this article shows how you can log Create, Alter, and Drop table statements, which include changes to constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One you create a table, you can create trigger to store changes to database. 
Full Article: http://www.sqlbook.com/sql-server/using-ddl-triggers-in-sql-server-to-audit-database-objects/

```
CREATE TRIGGER AuditProcChanges
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_PROC, ALTER_PROC, DROP_PROC, CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE
AS

DECLARE @ed XML
SET @ed = EVENTDATA()

INSERT INTO DDLAudit (PostTime, DatabaseName, Event, ObjectName, TSQL, Login) 
VALUES
(
    GetDate(),
    @ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
    @ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    @ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
    @ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)'),
    @ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout the following thread link for help.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0dfea12c-4133-42ff-b6fa-4b0f78cdfb33/audit-foreign-key-constraints?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Answer (score 0):

Stivan provided the answer to my question in the comments above.  If he submits it as an answer I will switch that to the accepted answer.  That being said, I added a DDL auditing table to the DB I wanted to track and a DB trigger to populate it when Create/Alter/Drop Table statements were executed.  The query I ran is shown below:

```
USE DBName
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DDLAudit](
    [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PostTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [Event] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ObjectName] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [TSQL] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [Login] [varchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DDLAudit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RowID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

CREATE TRIGGER AuditProcChanges
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE
AS

DECLARE @ed XML
SET @ed = EVENTDATA()

INSERT INTO DDLAudit (PostTime, DatabaseName, Event, ObjectName, TSQL, Login) 
VALUES
(
GetDate(),
@ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
@ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
@ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
@ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(2000)'),
@ed.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
)
```